# Как из BufferedImage - перевести картинку в пиксели?

Tags: java, изображения

как  из `BufferedImage` - перевести картинку в  пиксели?

Использую...
`javax.imageio.ImageIO` - умеет грузить картинки как объекты `BufferedImage`.
`javax.swing.JLabel` - умеет отображать иконки.
`javax.swing.ImageIcon` - умеет загружать картинки как иконки.
`BufferedImage` - там есть методы манипуляции с пикселями, а вот как проводить анализ - уже сложнее.

Answer (score 1):

Для получения массива пикселей из объекта класса `BufferedImage` можно использовать [следующий](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470843/7129209) способ:

```
private static int[][] convertTo2DWithoutUsingGetRGB(BufferedImage image) {

    final byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    final int width = image.getWidth();
    final int height = image.getHeight();
    final boolean hasAlphaChannel = image.getAlphaRaster() != null;

    int[][] result = new int[height][width];
    if (hasAlphaChannel) {
        final int pixelLength = 4;
        for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel += pixelLength) {
            int argb = 0;
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel] & 0xff) << 24); // alpha
            argb += ((int) pixels[pixel + 1] & 0xff); // blue
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 2] & 0xff) << 8); // green
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 3] & 0xff) << 16); // red
            result[row][col] = argb;
            col++;
            if (col == width) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }
    } else {
        final int pixelLength = 3;
        for (int pixel = 0, row = 0, col = 0; pixel < pixels.length; pixel += pixelLength) {
            int argb = 0;
            argb += -16777216; // 255 alpha
            argb += ((int) pixels[pixel] & 0xff); // blue
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 1] & 0xff) << 8); // green
            argb += (((int) pixels[pixel + 2] & 0xff) << 16); // red
            result[row][col] = argb;
            col++;
            if (col == width) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Данный метод основан на использовании объекта класса `DataBufferByte` с последующим получением из него массива пикселей.

Также, в классе `BufferedImage` есть метод [`getRGB(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)), который возвращает цвет заданного пикселя в модели `RGB`.

С помощью него можно получить массив цветов пикселей:

```
int[][] pixelsArray = new int[w][h];

for (int i=0; i<w; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<h; j++) {
        pixelsArray[i][j] = bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j);
    }
}
```

, где `w` и `h` – размеры изображения в пикселях, а `bufferedImage` – объект класса `BufferedImage`.

Однако, если Вам нужно получить массив всех пикселей, то целесообразно использовать первый способ, так как он более эффективный (хоть и не такой очевидный).

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы представить `BufferedImage` в виде массива пикселей, можно воспользоваться классом PixelGrabber и его методом grabPixels(). Например так:

```
void grabPixels(BufferedImage image) {
 int[] pixels;

 int width = image.getWidth();
 int height = image.getHeight();

 try {
  pixels = new int[width * height];

  PixelGrabber pgb = new PixelGrabber(image, 0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);

  pgb.grabPixels();
 } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
  System.out.println("Interrupted: " + exc.getMessage());
 }

 //Ваш код
}
```

Перед этим нужно импортировать класс PixelGrabber. Например так:

```
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
```

В строке `//Ваш код` Вам будет доступен одномерный массив `pixels` содержащий в себе все пиксели изображения `image`. Если же нужен массив двумерный можно обращаться точке `(x;y)` по формуле pixels[y * width + x] или написать небольшой конвертер. Например так:

```
int[][] pixels2D = int[width][height];

for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
 for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
  pixels2D[x][y] = pixels[y * width + x];
 }
}

//Ваш код 2
```

В строке `//Ваш код 2` Вам будет доступен двумерный массив `pixels2D`. Обратиться к пикселю `(x;y)` можно, например так:

```
pixels2D[x][y]
```

Конструктор PixelGrabber:

```
PixelGrabber(Image изображение, int слева, int сверху, int ширина,
 int высота, int массив[], int смещение, int ширина_строки_развертки)
```

Сигнатура метода grabPixels():

```
boolean grabPixels() throws InterruptedException
boolean grabPixels(long время_ожидания_пикселей_в_миллисекундах) throws
 InterruptedException
```